# Move multiple Dom element using array of anonymous coordinate

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates, nearest-neighbor

Im currently trying to move some div using an array of fresh coordinate.

The array is dynamically created by a face detection libs(face-api.js). This output a boundingBox with x/y coordinate.

Using one div there is no problem to bind the first coordinate to the Dom element.
But with multiple coordinate i struggle to find the right way.

[image: Face-Api.js div mapping]

The array change constantly and multiple div dont follow the detection.
I tried a implementation of the nearest neighbor algo.

I tried to sort the anon coordinate then sort my div coordinate and loop to apply the anon coordinates to every div.

Here is the code example for one frame :

```
...
let processResult = [{ x: 123}, {x: 456}, {x:789}]
let availableDiv = [xa, xb, xc , xd , xe, xf]

processResult.sort( (a, b) => parseInt(a.detection.box.x) - parseInt(b.detection.box.x));
availableDiv.sort( (a, b) => {
  parseInt(a.selector.getBoundingClientRect().x) - parseInt(b.selector.getBoundingClientRect().x)
});

processResult.forEach( (item, resultsIndex) => {

if (availableDiv.length > 0 && processResult.length > 0 ) {

  closest = availableDiv[0];
  function DistSquared(pt1, pt2) {
    var diffX = parseInt(pt1.left) - parseInt(pt2.left);
    var diffY = parseInt(pt1.height) - parseInt(pt1.height);
    return (diffX*diffX+diffY*diffY);
  }

  let shortestDistance = DistSquared(myPosition, availableFuseau[0]);

  for (let avaIndex = 0; avaIndex < availableDiv.length; avaIndex++) {
     var d = DistSquared(myPosition, availableDiv[avaIndex].selector.style);
     if (d < shortestDistance) {
        closest = availableDiv[avaIndex];
        closest.index = avaIndex
        shortestDistance = d;
     }
}

availableDiv.splice(closest.index, 1)

// change div coordinate
...
```

The main goal is to make smooth transition between two frame / coordinates changes and most importantly select the right Div element every frame...

Does someone have a clue to help me ?